# apply tactics works, but the variables in goal and hypothesis are different

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

Playing with leb_complete theorem from IndProp I found the following weirdness:

```
Theorem leb_complete : forall n m,
  n <=? m = true -> n <= m.
Proof.
  induction n as [|n'].
  - intros. apply O_le_n.
  - induction m as [| m'] eqn:Em.
    + intros H. discriminate H.
    + intros H. apply n_le_m__Sn_le_Sm.
```

It produces the following:

```
1 subgoal (ID 155)

n' : nat
IHn' : forall m : nat, (n' <=? m) = true -> n' <= m
m, m' : nat
Em : m = S m'
IHm' : m = m' -> (S n' <=? m') = true -> S n' <= m'
H : (S n' <=? S m') = true
============================
n' <= m'
```

Everything is fine. Now when I run `apply IHn'.` it works and produces the following:

```
(n' <=? m') = true
```

Why does it work? In IHn' we have

```
n' <= m - in IHn'
n' <= m' - in the goal
```

Variable m and `m'` are different, but it still works. When I tried

```
`rewrite -> Em in IHn'.
```

it gave an error:

```
Found no subterm matching "m" in IHn'.
```

But there is variable "m" in IHn'! I am confused, please, explain what's going on here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `m` in `IHn'` is just a dummy variable. `IHn'` quantifies over all natural numbers: `forall m : nat, [...]`. In particular, `m'` is a `nat`, so the hypothesis applies with `m` replaced with `m'`.

The `m` in `IHn'` is not the same as the one in your context (and in particular not the same as `m` in `Em : m = S m'`). They just happen to have the same name.